# If I use "noindex" on my blogs category pages should I add "nofollow" to the posts inside that category

Tags: seo, nofollow, noindex

Lets say I will use "noindex" on my blogs category pages

Each post has breadcrumb navigation like:
Home > Category Name > Post Name
If category has no index, I should add a rel="nofollow" to the link towards the category.
I mean there is no need to parse link juices for a cateogry which will not be indexed. This way, the posts from my category will pass link juices only to my index page. Right?

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you use nofollow [PageRank is still "lost" to those links even if those pages don't actually get it](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/pagerank-sculpting/) .  So you won't be accomplishing anything by doing this.

Comment: What If I use javascript to make the link? Than the html will just feature a html text and not an actual link... the link would be loaded with javascript and rel nofloow

Comment: If the link is created with JavaScript it will not be subject to nofollow and it will not be found by the search engines (if it is done correctly).

Comment: John, Actually Google does run a certain amount of your JavaScript, so I'm not so sure that would be 100% accurate as of 2014. They run the JavaScript to see what/how you change the content of the page because they count visible links and do not count (or rather possibly penalize) invisible links.